# List custom categories

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, categories

I want to display custom categories with their sub-categories in a nested list.

This seems to works:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&depth=2&hierarchical=1&title_li='); ?>
```

but if I include some custom categories it doesn't:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&depth=2&hierarchical=1&title_li=&include=7,8,1,4'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `include` parameter in query functions like this overrides all other parameters.  That is, you'll only get back the categories that you include rather than the ones you include plus the ones queried for by the other parameters.

The query_posts, get_posts, and WP_Query constructs work like this, too.

Comment: Oh, so is there any plugin that would allow me to list custom categories in custom order?